# High temperature phonon heat capacity and equipartition theorem

Tags: thermodynamics, condensed-matter, lattice-model, phonons

I have seen the derivation of the high temperature heat capatcity sing integration of the density of states. The heat capacity is $C=3Nk_B$ with $N$ the number of atoms in the lattice. According to my lecturer 'this is in agreement with the equipartition theorem'. While I agree that the dependence on the temperature and the number of atoms is the same, I would think that the equiparition theorem would predict $C=\frac{3}{2}Nk_B$, i.e. $1/2 k_B T$ of energy per quadratic degree of freedom, and there are 3N modes: N atoms, 2 transverse and 1 lngitudinal vibrational mode. Where did the factor of 2 go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are actually six quadratic degrees of freedom per atom: the three vibrational *potential* energies, which are quadratic in displacement, and the three *kinetic* energies, which are quadratic in velocity. This gives you the proper specific heat.

Answer (score 1):

Each mode is an independent harmonic oscillator. Thus, there is a quadratic kinetic energy term **and** a quadratic potential energy term in the Hamiltonian of each normal mode. Therefore the average total energy is $3Nk_BT$.